# Android JNI FindClass not finding R.id

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-resources

I am trying to find the value for a resource id. The first step of loading R class fails:

```
jclass rcl = (*env).FindClass("my/package/R$id");
```

the value of rcl is NULL.  I tried

```
jclass rcl = (*env).FindClass("my/package/R/id");
```

which also returns null.

Finding other classes such as MainActivity working fine. Using NDK15. What could be wrong?

Output of javap:
http://siara.cc/output.txt

EDITED:
On changing class name to just my/package/R, I find the following line in the adb log:

```
exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.package.R" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.package-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/my.package-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/my.package-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

Comment: what does `javap` says?

Comment: @pskink.. pls see i have given above output of javap

Comment: same output for R$id.class as well. strange..

Comment: however when i decompile R.class, I can find my ids there.. no issue there..

Comment: try `-v` to make it verbose

Comment: pls see the link.. if i paste the output it says too much code.. basically it shows the inner class in the output..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding proguard rule like this:

```
-keep class my.package.R$* { *; }
```

It appears that proguard obfuscates R class as well.